# Completion of a function space with sup metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $(Y , d)$ be a metric space. Let $(\mathcal B(X,Y), ρ)$ be the
set of all bounded functions from $X$ to $(Y,d)$ endowed with the sup-metric $ρ$ defined as follows.

$$\forall f,g \in \mathcal B(X , Y) \quadρ(f,g) := \sup\{ d(f(x),g(x)) : x \in X \}.$$
I know that the metric space $(\mathcal B(X,Y), ρ)$ is complete if and only if the metric space $(Y,d)$ is complete.

Now, assume that $(Y,d)$ is not complete and let $(Z,d)$ be a completion of $(Y, d)$.

Let $(\mathcal B(X,Z), ρ)$ be the set of all bounded functions from $X$ to $(Z,d)$ endowed with the sup-metric. Then how to prove that the metric space $(\mathcal B(X,Z), ρ)$ is a completion of the metric space $(\mathcal B(X,Y), ρ)$?

I assume that it is true and if not then can we get a counterexample. If $X$ is finite then it is easy for me to prove it, but I am struggling if $X$ is infinite.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Given metric spaces $A$ and $B$ where $B$ is complete, one has that $B$ is the completion of $A$ if and only if there exists a distance preserving embedding $A \hookrightarrow B$ with dense image. Does that help you in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The function $T$ that sends $f \in B(X,Y)$, so $f:X \to Y$, to $T(f)= e \circ f: X \to Z$ in $B(X,Z)$, where $e: (Y,d_Y) \to (Z,d_Z)$ is the distance preserving embedding of $Y$ into its completion, is also distance preserving, as is easy to check.

It's also easy to check that the image of $T$ is dense in $B(X,Z)$, based on the fact that $e[Y]$ is dense in $Z$.

It follows that $T$ witnesses that $B(X,Z)$ is a (or the, up to isometry) completion of $B(X,Y)$, by standard facts from the theory of completions.

Comment: Can you please give some hint , how image of T is dense in B(X , Z) because e[Y]  is dense in (Z ,d).

Comment: @mpandey Let $B(f,r)$ be any uniform ball in $B(X,Z)$ around some $f: X to Z$, $r>0$, we need only show that it intersects the image of $T$. For each $x \in X$, pick any $y_x \in Y$ such that $d_Z(e(y_x), f(x)) \le \frac12 r$ which can be done by denseness of $e[Y]$. Etc.

Comment: Thank You very much. Now it is clear.